# Can't set startup configuration

Tags: interface

I am using Blender 2.83 on Windows. I start Blender and it starts in full screen mode. I resize the window and move it, then use Ctrl-U or File->Defaults->Save Startup File but when I quit Blender and restart, it goes back to full screen as if I never saved a startup file. According to the docs, it should be saving a file called startup.blend, but that is nowhere on my system. I do see a userpref.blend created in a config directory but that does not have any affect on the startup window. I found the userpref.blend in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\config and I also tried to create a config directory in C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\ but only userpref.blend ever gets created there, never startup.blend. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The location you're looking at is correct and it should work. I've tested this in 2.83.5 and the latest master build. Is there any error message printed on the console after attempting to save (*Window > Toggle System Console*)?

Comment: To save the start up file it is : File > Defaults > Save Start up File and then appears a little popup "OK: "Save Start up File" which needs to be clicked on as conformation.. Just checking that you are doing the second "Save Start up File" thing because if you move the mouse away to quickly that conformation popup disappears before you get the chance to click on it .

Comment: Ah, you are right about the confirmation box. I never saw it. Probably because I moved my mouse away after the save command, not expecting I would have to confirm the save. That fixed it. Thanks!